# Solving Nonlinear System of Equation using 'nleqslv' package

Tags: r

I need some help on knowing the package `nleqslv` in R. Given the code below, I wish to solve a 3 variables non-linear equation.

E.g:

```
library(nlseqslv)
f <- function(x) {
  y <- numeric(3)
  y[1] <- x[1] + x[2] - x[1] * x[2] - 2
  y[2] <- x[1] + x[3] - x[1] * x[3] - 3
  y[3] <- x[2] + x[3] - 4
  return(y)
}

xstart <- c(2, 1, 0.5)
fstart <- dslnex(xstart)

# Newton start
nleqslv(xstart, f, 
        control = list(trace = 1, btol = .01, delta = "newton"))
```

Consider a constant variable `i` for `i = 1` to `i = 100`, for example:

```r
For i = 1:100 {
  f <- function(x) {
    y <- numeric(3)
    y[1] <- i * (x[1] + x[2] - x[1] * x[2]) - 2
    y[2] <- i * (x[1] + x[3] - x[1] * x[3]) - 3
    y[3] <- i * (x[2] + x[3]) - 4
    return(y)
  }
}

xstart <- c(2, 1, 0.5)
fstart <- dslnex(xstart)

# Newton start
nleqslv(xstart, f, 
        control = list(trace = 1, btol = .01, delta = "newton"))
```

Am I able to obtain the results of the 3 unknown variables `x1`, `x2` and `x3` for each i = 1, 2, 3, ..., 100?

Comment: So where exactly does `f` come back? Or did you mean to define `dslnex` instead of `f`?

Comment: hi sorry, the function f is defined as dslnex. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Your function f` is NOT defined as `dslnex`. Just look at your code. `f` has a vector of length 3 as input but `dslnex` has a vector of length 2 as input.

Comment: Your code cannot run. Missing a `library(nleqslv)` statement. You can only use `dslnex` after you run `example(nleqslv)`. Olease provide correct runnable code.

Comment: Thanks for the input. All suggested inputs have been corrected in the R code.

Comment: Sorry to say this. You have NOT corrected all issues. You are still using `dslnex` which only exists AFTER running `example(nleqslv)`. You use of `.. dslnex` is superfluous. It serves no purpose in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I will not show the result of running this code as it would make the answer much too large.

Code for solving function

```
library(nleqslv)

f <- function(x) {
  y <- numeric(3)
  y[1] <- x[1] + x[2] - x[1] * x[2] - 2
  y[2] <- x[1] + x[3] - x[1] * x[3] - 3
  y[3] <- x[2] + x[3] - 4
  return(y)
}
```

Starting value

```
xstart <- c(2, 1, 0.5)

nleqslv(xstart, f,
        control = list(trace = 1, btol = .01, delta = "newton"))
```

And now run `testnslv` to see if another method or global search works better

```
testnslv(xstart,f)
```

Looking at the result one can see that using the Newton method with no global search mechanism
is the quickest.

Define function with extra parameter i

```
f2 <- function(x,i) {
    y <- numeric(3)
    y[1] <- i * (x[1] + x[2] - x[1] * x[2]) - 2
    y[2] <- i * (x[1] + x[3] - x[1] * x[3]) - 3
    y[3] <- i * (x[2] + x[3]) - 4
    return(y)
}

nleqslv(xstart, f2,i=1,
        control = list(trace = 1, btol = .01, delta = "newton"))
```

Same solution as above

Let `i` vary from 1 to 100 and store the (possible) solutions in a matrix together with the termination code
so that you can check if a solution was found

```
xstart <- rep(0.5,3)
zR <- matrix(NA,nrow=100,ncol=4)
for( i in 1:100 ) {
   z <-  nleqslv(xstart,f2,i=i,control = list(btol = .01, delta = "newton"))
   zR[i,] <- c(z$x,z$termcd)
   xstart <- z$x
}
zR
```

No solution for `i=2`.

Why would that be the case?
With some algebraic manipulation one can derive an explicit solution.

```
zsol <- matrix(NA,nrow=100,ncol=4)
for( i in 1:100 ) {
zsol[i,1] <- 1/(2*i-4)
zsol[i,2] <- (2/i-zsol[i,1])/(1-zsol[i,1])
zsol[i,3] <- (3/i-zsol[i,1])/(1-zsol[i,1])
zsol[i,4] <- 1
}
zsol
# check the explicit solution with the solution found by `nleqslv`
zsol - zR
```

When `i=2` there is division by 0 for the first element of a solution vector.

Run this code and enjoy.